# Does a video card for PCI-E x16 work in a PCI-E x4 slot?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard

Is there a problem if I put a video card for PCI-E x16 into a PCI-E x4 slot? How does it affect its speed?

Comment: I'd rephrase this so it doesn't sound like a buying recommendation.

Comment: i want to use a video card not to buy but i don't know is it compatible with the motherboard

Comment: I answered the question, first link in Google when you search your motherboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_775/P5VDCX/)

```
1 x PCI-E X16 (max. X4 mode)
```

Comment: Can you give me some example video card that can be use?

Comment: If you Google those kinds of graphics cards you'll find tons.

Answer (score 1):

Any PCI-E card will work in that slot (2.0 cards should be backwards compatible with 1.0 slots), but the bandwidth is cut down considerably.

If you're buying it for gaming, cards made in 2007 began bottlenecking PCIe 4x.
http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/pci-express-scaling-analysis,1572-8.html

Might want to consider that.